# I created a nice looking ocean but I cant get it to move... Can you help?

Tags: video

I followed the instructions of this tutorial, to create a nice looking ocean for my project:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqsOH-qToHs

I am done now, it looks fantastic but when I render it out as a video it does not move. I then rewatched the video to make sure I did everything as stated. But I cant find a clue.

Can you help, do you have advice?

Answer (score 0):

Set your start and end frame
[image: Setting end frame]

Select render as animation
[image: Render as animation]

This will generate an image sequence which you can then convert to video by following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmxaYwmewWs)